# How to handle illegal strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I have a logging function which writes error messages to a file.

The cause of a particular error is a file not found, not because the file does not exist, but because of a typo error of backslashes.

For example, my application code is trying to open a file from the string `'d:\\reports\2015\\a.txt'`, which has a missing `'\'` before `2015`.  The `except` clause passes control to the logging function with the filename as an argument, but when the logging function tries to write the string containing the erroneous file name, it too crashes with a charmap codec error.

How do I write out safely anything and everything that is contained within a pair of quotation marks?

---

From the comments received thus far, I guess my question is not clear.

What I am asking is not about file names per se.  What I trying to solve is an error logging function - writing an error message to a file - that will work no matter what the error message is.  In the example above, the error message passed to the logging function contains an illegal string.

Comment: Where did you get the string from? Is it har-coded in a code? Because single backlash in a non-raw string is an escape character.

Comment: If the illegal strings always refer to a file path, then you could use the `normpath()` method from `os.path` to normalize your path strings. https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath

Comment: Looks like a codec error. Could you paste the log string and corresponding error message here?

Answer (score 0):

You error should happen if you are putting the file name into the code directly. Then you should fix the code and it  might be good to use the `r` marker: `r'd:\reports\2015\a.txt'`.

Comment: My idea for the logging function was to record errors that a user for my library may make.  So if the user makes a typo, it should log the error gracefully rather than crash. I could put a try/except around the logging function and report that error instead of saving/printing the original data that was causing the problem.